# "Keyboard not responding" in emulator?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-emulator, notepad

I'm using Android 2.1 SDK on MacOS 10.6.2.

When I try to run the standard Notepad app in the emulator, I get the expected messages from Eclipse

```
[2010-01-18 17:42:24 - NotesList]New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2010-01-18 17:42:24 - NotesList]Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2010-01-18 17:42:26 - Emulator]2010-01-18 17:42:26.567 emulator[96730:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.

[2010-01-18 17:43:31 - NotesList]HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2010-01-18 17:43:31 - NotesList]Uploading NotesList.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2010-01-18 17:43:32 - NotesList]Installing NotesList.apk...

[2010-01-18 17:43:55 - NotesList]Success!

[2010-01-18 17:43:55 - NotesList]Starting activity com.example.android.notepad.NotesList on device 

[2010-01-18 17:44:06 - NotesList]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.android.notepad/.NotesList }
```

Then it starts to go wrong.   A dialog flashes on to the screen too fast for me to read it.

Then notepad starts (I have to "unlock" the screen manually by dragging the lock tag)

Then there is a "Force close or wait" dialog that announces "*Application Android keyboard (in process com.android.inputmethod.latin) is not responding.*"

The app won't do anything further at this point.  I have not made any changes to the app.

Has anyone else seen this error ?

Does anyone have advice on how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the "keyboard not responding" error before, but I've always assumed that it was because the emulator was running slowly on my machine (and Android thinking that the process was awry and needed to be killed).  When I click "wait" on the popup, it stalls for a few seconds, but then goes into a working state.

Comment: This approach seems to work.  Please let me know if I am supposed to toggle something to acknowledge the helpful answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry dude, but I had to vote this down.  You did not answer the question.  You just said, click yeah yeah and it'll pass.  But that's not the question!  The question was if it can be avoided.